# Draft entry owners' record lost in list item (which uses content approval) are lost

Tags: sharepoint-server, custom-list, versioning, content-approval

I have a custom list in sharepoint 2010. It includes a "Description" column which allows appending changes to existing text. It is needed to track who has entered the comment to any list item. This list also includes content approval cycle.

When a user writes his comments on a list item and the project leader approves the entries. On the "Description" column it is seen as the project leader made the comment. However it is written by an project member. Additionally on version history we can only see the project leader's revisions after the approval.

Does anyone see such a problem before?